# errors with \fbox and parenthesis

Tags: boxes

So I'm doing a LaTeX tutorial and trying to recreate a LaTeX document where a pair of tables are in parenthesis, in a box, in a list. I've come upon this error when I try to use both \fbox and \left( and \right).

```
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item{
\fbox{  
    \[
    \left(
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
            \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.15in}
            $\overbrace{\int_{1}^{3}\frac{1}{t}\emph{dt}}$ & $|\mathbf{-}4|$ \\ 
            \hline 
            \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.40in}
            $\oint \mathbf{B}\cdot d$\textbf{a} & \textbf{A} \\ 
    \end{tabular}
        \right)
        \]

    $\stackrel{?}{=}$

        \[
        \left(
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.50in}$\underbrace{\ln 3}$ & $4$ \\
        \hline
        \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.40in}0 & $\frac{1}{4\pi}\int \frac{BX\dot{R}}{R^2}d\tau'$ \\
    \end{tabular}
        \right)
        \]
    }
}
\item By completing the square, solve the equation $2\emph{x}^2+8\emph{x}+1=0$.

\textbf{Solution:}
\bigskip
\begin{center}
    $2x^2+8x+1=0$ 
\end{center}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

For some reason, if I don't include the code for the parenthesis, it comes out boxed, or if I exclude the code for the box, it can have parenthesis. But when I try both, I get the errors about missing $ and missing }. Can somebody tell me the interaction I'm missing here, because I can't see the issue.

The errors are:

```
Missing $ inserted. }
Bad math environment delimiter. }
Missing $ inserted. }
Missing } inserted. }
Missing $ inserted. }
Bad math environment delimiter. }
Extra }, or forgotten $. }
Extra }, or forgotten $. }
Extra }, or forgotten $. }
Command \item invalid in math mode. \item
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \item B
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \item B
Missing $ inserted. ...the square, solve the equation $2\emph{x}^
Missing \endgroup inserted. \begin{center}
Missing } inserted. \begin{center}
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{center}
\begin{enumerate} on input line 16 ended by \end{center}. \end{center}
Missing } inserted. \end{center}
\begin{document} ended by \end{enumerate}. \end{enumerate}
Extra \endgroup. \end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you please make your code copy-paste-compilable? I realise that it won't compile, but we want to copy-paste-compile... and get the error you want help with. Right now, that won't happen. Also, please report exact error messages. They are much more useful than your summary or interpretation. (If you understand the error well enough to do that, you understand it well enough to fix it without asking.)

Comment: You can't use `\[...\]` inside `\fbox`.

Comment: Why are you using `\emph{}` in maths mode? And `\textbf{}`? Wouldn't `array` be more suitable than `tabular`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have vertical spacing / a paragraph break within `\fbox{}` but display maths sets its content off separately. You can keep `\fbox` happy by using a `\parbox` within the `\fbox`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item{
    \fbox{
      \parbox{.8\linewidth}{%
        \[
        \left(
        \begin{tabular}{c|c}
          \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.15in}
          $\overbrace{\int_{1}^{3}\frac{1}{t}\emph{dt}}$ & $|\mathbf{-}4|$ \\
          \hline
          \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.40in}
          $\oint \mathbf{B}\cdot d$\textbf{a} & \textbf{A} \\
        \end{tabular}
        \right)
        \]

        $\stackrel{?}{=}$

        \[
        \left(
        \begin{tabular}{c|c}
          \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.50in}$\underbrace{\ln 3}$ & $4$ \\
          \hline
          \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.40in}0 & $\frac{1}{4\pi}\int \frac{BX\dot{R}}{R^2}d\tau'$ \\
        \end{tabular}
        \right)
        \]
      }
    }
  }
  \item By completing the square, solve the equation $2\emph{x}^2+8\emph{x}+1=0$.

  \textbf{Solution:}
  \bigskip
  \begin{center}
    $2x^2+8x+1=0$
  \end{center}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Do you really want the additional vertical space added by the `center` environment, on top of `\bigskip` and that added by `\end{enumerate}`? Some of this may just get cancelled, of course, but not always and this will often not give the output you want.

Nesting maths environments like that cannot be good, either....

Also:

- `\item` does not take a mandatory argument: the syntax is `\item[<label>] stuff`;
- don't use `\emph{}` in maths mode;
- ditto `\textbf{}`.
- a new line means a space - comment new lines to avoid spurious spacing;
- probably `array` is better than `tabular` here.

But nesting maths environments still seems dodgy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item %
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}%
      \[
      \left(
      \begin{array}{c|c}
        \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.15in}%
        \overbrace{\int_{1}^{3}\frac{1}{t}dt} & |\mathbf{-}4| \\
        \hline
        \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.40in}
        \oint \mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{a} & \mathbf{A} \\
      \end{array}
      \right)
      \]

      \[\stackrel{?}{=}\]

      \[
      \left(
      \begin{array}{c|c}
        \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.50in}\underbrace{\ln 3} & 4 \\
        \hline
        \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.40in}0 & \frac{1}{4\pi}\int \frac{BX\dot{R}}{R^2}d\tau' \\
      \end{array}
      \right)
      \]
    \end{minipage}%
  }
  \item By completing the square, solve the equation $2x^2+8x+1=0$.

  \textbf{Solution:}
  \[
    2x^2+8x+1=0
  \]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: tweaked a bit]

Comment: The pair of matrxies are ment to be on the same line. How do I put a Prenthesis around a table without \{ or \]? [This is the actual document that I'm trying to recreate](https://s3.amazonaws.com/piazza-resources/idyx9p5txda4jh/ifjann4m2g49n/Project_3_Part_2_and_3_ver_1.0.9.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJKOQYKAYOBKKVTKQ&Expires=1444435182&Signature=YBeIbTXo0hs2EM39tc7TM7D9io0%3D)

Comment: [sorry, put wrong link. fixed now.](https://s3.amazonaws.com/piazza-resources/idyx9p5txda4jh/ifgg0a5gsbn72r/project3_latexpart2.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJKOQYKAYOBKKVTKQ&Expires=1444435263&Signature=uB7z1G40BVJ3vdk%2Bcc%2BvZ6R27CQ%3D)

Comment: @James I can't view that link - I just get an error. The same line as each other?

Comment: @James Still get an error with the new link. It says there is no style information belonging to the XML and then lists the document tree. (This is a rough translation - the error is not in English.)

Comment: [ok, maybe this time the link will work](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B26eeSkfEW-aNWlxQksxNktaYk0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @James Can you use packages? What are you trying to do this for exactly?

Comment: @James Is this homework or just something you're learning on your own? If the latter, I guess packages are fine?

Comment: It's for an introductory class. I'm just trying to recreate a pdf that the professor gave us.

Comment: @James Can't you ask for the code? If this is for credit, we probably shouldn't do it all for you ;).

Comment: It's ok, the call with Array instead of Tabular was right.  this got me what I was looking for:
    \fbox{ 
 
  $\left(

  \begin{array}{c|c}

    \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.15in}

    \overbrace{\int_{1}^{3}\frac{1}{t}dt} & |-4| \\ 

    \hline 

    \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.40in}

    \oint \mathbf{B}\cdot d\textbf{a} & \mathbf{A} \\ 
  \end{array}
  \right)$

  $\stackrel{?}{=}$ 

  $\left(

  \begin{array}{c|c}

   \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.50in}\underbrace{\ln 3} & 4 \\

   \hline

   \rule[-.15in]{0in}{0.40in}0 & \frac{1}{4\pi}\int \frac{BX\dot{R}}{R^2}d\tau' \\
  \end{array}
  \right)$
  }

Comment: @James Try putting both your `array` environments (and the stack in between) within a single display maths environment. That will let you get them all on one line. I think you will almost be there then ;).

Comment: @James Or that ;).

Comment: yup, I got it. Thanks for the help, and sorry for the messy formatting. As you can probably tell, I'm new to around here.

Comment: @James You're welcome - just so as I am not helping you in some way your instructor would consider cheating. (I'm not suggesting you are - just be careful. It is easy to be so used to getting help on the net that you can forget easily.)